# how to send null file in multipart/form-data request OR how to display browser's output stream

Tags: file, stream, null, output, multipartform-data

in my android java application I build multipart/form-data requests. If I add a file into a request it looks like this (this is only the part with file of course):

```
--boundary\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="<fieldName>";\r\n
filename="<filename>"\r\n
Content-Type: <mime-type>\r\n
\r\n
<file-data>\r\n
```

It works great usually. But problem is if I want to send "empty file". I don't know how output stream should look like then. Basically I want the same request as sends browser which has this code:

```
<form action="http://example.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="nothing_selected_here" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and I don't choose any file.

OR if you know a way how to display browser's output stream it would be the best. I can see how a browser sends it then.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had only small mistake in my try (finename instead of filename).
It should look like this, if it is empty:

```
--boundary\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="<fieldName>";\r\n
filename=""\r\n
Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
```

Here you can monitor request in Firefox:
Tools > Web developer > Network
I just found it.